# How can I build a firestore query for Android with whereGreaterthan() filters for two different fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter the list of my documents which I am fetching from `firestore` in my android `app`. this is the query.

```
  query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("students")
            .whereLessThan("mAge",25)
            .whereGreaterThan("mAge",20)
            .whereGreaterThan("mGrades",20);
```

but, I get an error in the log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dsardy.in.acchebacche/dsardy.in.acchebacche.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'mAge' and 'mGrades'

Can this be achieved? a filter with two or more fields greater than some values is an important and general query, `firestore` must have something to tackle this.

Answer (score 4):

Firestore allows to chain multiple inequality conditions to create more specific queries, but only on the same field. As you can probably see in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) range filters on different fields are forbidden.

To achieve what you want, you need to query your database twice, once to fiter data using `.whereGreaterThan("mAge",20)` and second using `.whereGreaterThan("mGrades",20)` but you cannot use them in the same query.

Another way to make it happen is to store a special field that might fit the query, although in real world applications it will almost impossible to store every single way a user might query the data.

Comment: is there any alternate way to read question according to given tags in an array . https://stackoverflow.com/q/52096781/3496570  I mean if whereArrayContains cannot be used. There must be another way round.

Comment: @XarEAhmer Why do you say `whereArrayContains` cannot be used? Sure it can. Can you please post a new question to understand better what you are looking for?