# Fetch collection on basis of array item gives "FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch all questions which has "maths" tag, but instead of success it moves to failedListener.

```
db.collection("questionCollection")
                .orderBy("questionID", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .whereArrayContains("tags","maths")
                .limit(3)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                            return;
                        } else {
                            // Convert the whole Query Snapshot to a list
                            // of objects directly! No need to fetch each
                            // document.
                            questionList = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(QuestionBO.class);

                            if (questionList != null && questionList.size() > 0)
                                mAdapter.updateQuestions(questionList);
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

[image]

**Exception**

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/testingproject-384af/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EhJxd
```

Comment: so what is the exception printed?

Comment: What is the exception that you get?

Comment: We're going to need more info on the issue. What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the exception. The query requires an indexes

Comment: So I guess exception already answers your question, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click the link given to you in that error message.  It will take you to  the console and ask you to create the index that will satisfy the query you're trying to perform.